# Using a graph file (.pb file) with tensorflow js for prediction

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm just getting started with [TensorFlow.JS](https://js.tensorflow.org/). 
I'm have a sample ".pb" file in my directory, which is a trained model. I'm trying to load this model to use it for prediction in one of a sample machine learning app I'm trying to build in the browser. As my understanding in this topic is very minimal, I could not find any useful information regarding this in the documentation. I've tried using

```
tf.loadModel(Model_URL, Weights_URL)
```

But giving the file path to this is throwing this error :

> URL scheme "file" is not supported.

Can anyone help me load this .pb file in the browser using Tfjs ?

Comment: As I understand it you need to pass the URL of the model config to `loadModel` and the library loads the rest of it. So you need to serve the model over http not file://

Comment: What if I want to load it from file ? Is it possible to load the file and pass it to loadModel ?

Comment: The documentation of loadModel only shows loading from http, local storage and local database. To serve the file start a local Webserver and provide loadModel the path to the model config file on the Webserver.

Comment: Yes. So I tried serving the .pb file from a local webserver and passed it to the loadModel method. It's still not working, throwing a JSON parse error. But the same works with a sample model.json file.

Comment: And you converted your model to tfjs-format using https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter?

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel I tried converting, but that command is not working in my mac terminal.

Comment: Can you file a bug with the error you're getting when you try to convert?

Comment: @AlexandrePassos The issue was with the .pb file I was trying to load. I've converted the file using tfjs-converter and now I'm able to load the model.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following line of code

```
const model = await tf.loadFrozenModel(Model_URL, Weights_URL);
```